# Suppress a process in linux kernel scheduler (not kill)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

In linux scheduler, I want to suppress some processes by modifying the scheduler code. Is it possible to suppress process without killing but just suppression?

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the context? Are you *very* familiar with user-space [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)? Why can't you code some user application and use [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Your question is **unclear** and **too broad** since lacking much more context

Comment: Maybe you want to [nice](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unice.htm) it to a different niceness

Comment: [Can a process be frozen temporarily in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/485884/can-a-process-be-frozen-temporarily-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the linux scheduler, I want to suppress some processes by modifying the scheduler code

Probably **not possible, and certainly ill defined.** The good way to think of *modifying the kernel* is first: *don't*, and later *don't yet*, and at last *minimally and carefully* !

What *exactly* "suppressing" a process is meaning to you? You might want to *terminate* it. You certainly cannot *simply* "suppress" some process, since the kernel is carefully cleaning up after it has terminated.

And why are you wanting to modify the kernel? In general, [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) and [user-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) is a better place to do such things (or even [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)). You might want to also have some [kernel thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#KERNEL) (very tricky).

You might consider kernel to user-space communication with [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html), then try to minimize your kernel footprint. Be however aware that the [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#SCHEDULER) is a critical, and very well tuned, piece of code inside the kernel.

In practice, I would suggest a *high-priority* user-land daemon. See [setpriority(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpriority.2.html), [nice(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html) and [sched(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html). We don't know what you want to achieve, but it is likely do be *practically doable* in user-land. And if it is not, perhaps Linux is not the right kernel for you (taking into account that you [Silvara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5307828/silvara) is a drone developer). Then look into genuine [real-time operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), IoT OSes like [Contiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiki), or [library operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)#Library) [unikernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unikernel) such as [MirageOS](https://mirage.io/).